# Specific data from EventLogEntry

Tags: c#, event-log

So I know how to access to each entries of an EventLog by using:

```
EventLog log = new EventLog("Security", //YourDomain);
foreach(EventLogEntry entry in log.Entries)
{
    //What ever you want to do with entry
}
```

But I need to access to these data:

[image]
Does anyone know how to proceed?

Comment: I've copied your answer into an actual answer. If you wish to answer this yourself please let me know and I'll delete the wiki I've added. You should avoid putting answers into questions

Answer (score 3):

*copied form OPs question*

So I found the solution on my own, hope it can help people!

Here is the solution:

```
//The query sort the evenlog so write the characteristics you need
string query = "*[System/Level=3 or Level=4]";

/*Select here the eventlog you want to watch, PathType.LogName and also the query you wrote right above*/
EventLogQuery eventsQuery = new EventLogQuery("System", PathType.LogName, query);
try
{
    EventLogReader logReader = new EventLogReader(eventsQuery);
    for (EventRecord eventdetail = logReader.ReadEvent(); eventdetail != null; eventdetail = logReader.ReadEvent())
    {
        //Get the XML for each entry
        /* /!\ eventdetail.ToXml() return a string, that's why you can use string properties*/
            var doc = eventdetail.ToXml();
        //Select the part of the XML you need
            int first = doc.IndexOf("<EventData>") + "<EventData>".Length;
            int last = doc.IndexOf("</EventData>");
            string finaldoc = doc.Substring(first, last - first);

        //Display the xml before and after selection
            Console.WriteLine(doc+System.Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine(finaldoc);
            Console.ReadKey();
   }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error while reading the event logs"+e.Message);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```